# reading the background color in javascript doesn't work - why?

Tags: javascript, dom, background-color

The following line of code produces an empty alertbox:

```
alert (document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor);
```

Of course, this is only a control, the background color would then be used in an if-clause.

The string variable x contains the id of a table data cell < td>< /td>.

x definitely exists. The line works when I test it with another style property such as document.getElementById(x).style.height.

The table cell x also has a defined background color. It was set in
javascript with

```
document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor = #00FF55
```

I also tested given color names like "lime", but to no avail.
Setting the background color with javascript works, reading it doesn't work.

I also tested the example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_backgroundcolor3), and it worked, so it's not a problem of my browser.

I've tinkered around the good part of a working day to make this work, still have no idea.

Comment: Are you seeing any console errors? I can't replicate your issue. May you edit the question to include the `x` DOM Element?

Comment: No console errors, I looked for these. It seems the color value is just read as an empty string...

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor = #00FF55
> ```

*SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token*.

String literals must be surrounded with `"` or `'`.

```
 document.getElementById("x").style.backgroundColor = "#00FF55";
```

You're failing to set the value, so it remains unset when you try to read it back.

Comment: x is of course a variable here. The line before reads:                     x= "TD_"+i.toString()+":"+Tag.toString();

Comment: @BigBene — That isn't what you said in the question, and doesn't stop the problem with the *colour* being invalid JavaScript.

Comment: "and doesn't stop the problem with the colour being invalid JavaScript" - OK, so why is it invalid? That's basically what I need to know.

Comment: @BigBene — Because it doesn't have quotes around it!

Comment: Is the ID valid, does it return a valid DOM element?

Comment: @Quentin: It's a variable, both in the line setting the value and the line where I tried to read it. Setting works, the cell changes it's color. Reading doesn't work. I already told it's a variable, I apologized for the wrong wording and I edited the question accordingly. Being a variable, it cannot have quotes around it. Sorry beeing repetitive, but aside from the quotes, what is wrong here?

Comment: @evolutionbox: Yes, it is. As I wrote, I tested it with the same code, just another property, namely height. The alert then gives the correct height of the cell (3px), so the id is definietly valid.

Comment: @BigBene — "It's a variable" — `#00FF55` is not a variable. A variable name cannot start with a `#`. You are either lying about your code or you are lying about the results. Provide a real [mcve].

Comment: I was of course talking about the x (representing the ID of the cell), not the #00FF55. #00FF55 is not a variable, but a fixed hex number. I have now put quotes around it in the code, but this didn't solve the problem. Providing a "minimal example" is difficult, as the code is part of a php page wich creates the table out of data from a sql table, and also includes code to verify the identity of the Session owner.

Comment: "I was of course talking about the x" — I wasn't. That's why I said "colour" and not "id". (Twice!)

Comment: "Providing a minimal example is difficult" — But necessary. Consult the guidelines at [mcve] for help creating one.

Answer (score 0):

Both the name of the id and the value after the `=` must be surrounded by `"..."`

Comment: Ok, then the problem should be the `"..."` that should surround the value of the color

Comment: I don't think so, because setting the color actually worked. But I will give it a try. Just a few minutes...

Comment: OK, now quotes are around the color definition both in the original definition of the cells:

Comment: OK, now quotes are around the color definition all in the original definition of the cells, the javascript code wich changes the color value via XXX.style.backgroundColor = "#hexvalue", and the code which tries to read it. Still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

I defined the cell background colors originally in (php created) HTML:

`<td ID ="x" name="nx" bgcolor=#00FF55 style="overflow: visible; border-left:1px solid grey"></td>`

I tried to set the hex value in quotes after reading the comments here, but this is not even allowed in the HTML syntax.

When background color was changed via javascript it was set as style property, which worked.
But reading the set color as style didn't.

I even had tried this solution before, setting the colors as styles from the beginning, but as this resulted in unwanted behaviour of the table, I discarded it. Now I reedited the table creating code and implemented setting the colors as style properties, and everything worked out.

I still think reading the background colors when they are set, even as HTML, should be possible.